# How to integrate the user interface api with an existing project?

Tags: oauth2, oauth, react, ui-api, user-interface-api

I am trying to implement a form in my react app that allows users to submit data to salesforce using the UI API.

From following the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) I have created a connected app with a callback url and enabled the OAuth settings from my DE Org.

In my react project I have created a simple form which just takes the user's name and email address:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UserForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="POST">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onFirstNameChange} />
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.onLastNameChange} />
                <label>Email address</label>
                <input type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEmailChange} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default UserForm;
```

My plan from here is for the `handleSubmit` function to make a post request to the api, by doing something like this:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    let postDataUrl = '/services/data/v51.0/ui-api/record-ui/';
    let request = {
        method: 'POST',
        'apiName': 'Account',
        'fields': {
            'First name': this.state.firstName,
            'Last name': this.state.lastName,
            'Email': this.state.email
        }
    }
    try {
        return (fetch, postFirstDataUrl, request)
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
};
```

However this is clearly wrong, and I am also confused about how to connect my code up to the Salesforce org I created. I have read tons of documentation and watched all the youtube clips I can find and am still stumped. Would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/pozil/salesforce-react-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) explains how to create an authorization code and retrieve an access token. I then passed the access token into my fetch request using headers and that resolved my issue:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    let postDataUrl = '/services/data/v51.0/ui-api/record-ui/';
    let authorize = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    try {
        return (fetch, postDataUrl, authorize )
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
};
```